# Convert date in format 2013-06-20T17:10:44.642 to NSDate

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert date 2013-06-20T17:10:44.642 to NSDate in Objective-C?

I have a django application that outputs the date in JSON and uses Objective-C to parse the date, but I need to turn an NSString in the format above to NSDate. How can I do that?

I know how to convert NSString to NSDATE but I don't know how to convert that specific date:2013-06-20T17:10:44.642

I have:

```
NSString        *iso8601String = dateString;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale        *locale         = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

But that is now working.

Comment: Samo, samo, samo, samo, samo...  Boring, boring, boring, boring...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using NSDateFormatter. Look at the `setDateFormat:` method. Then you can run `dateFromString:` to get an NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

I marked this as a duplicate before the code was posted. Now that there is concrete code that isn't working, I can help point out the problem.

Your format doesn't match. You need:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Also, the locale should be `en_US_POSIX`.

And don't set the format behavior. The default behavior is what you want.